# First usage of golem to refer to a man-made humanoid

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, hebrew, mysticism-kabbalah, maharal

There's a famous folk tale that the Maharal [created a golem](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%92), some sort of human shaped creature. The tale has it that he created it using practical Kabbalah.

[The gemarra](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin_65b.17) even describes amoraim creating a humanoid using Sefer Yetzira. However, the gemarra doesn't use the word golem.

[The Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.2.7.1), based on [Bereishis Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.8.1), says that Adam was created as a golem by Hashem, but obviously that wasn't a man-made golem.

The word, as I understand it, refers simply to a formless mass. It's used by the [Mishnah](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.7) to chastise uncivilized individuals. What's the earliest usage of the word golem to refer to a humanoid created by humans?

Answer (score 4):

The usage of ‘golem’ referring to a humanoid created by humans appears in a late 12th century-early 13th century commentary to [Sefer Yetzirah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_Yetzirah) by R. [Eleazar of Worms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) (Commentary, [p. 15b s.v. העוסק](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37671&st=&pgnum=34)) :

> ויש לו ליקח קרקע בתולה במקום הרים שלא חפר בה אדם שם, ויגבל העפר במים חיים ויעשה **גולם** אחד וכו׳

(Disclaimer: Don’t try this at home.)

In a manuscript, published by [Gershon Scholem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershom_Scholem) ([Kitvei Yad Be’Kabbalah p. 75 n. 26](https://archive.org/details/GershomScholemwithTheAssistanceOfIssacharJoelXxxxTMXTMxXxxxoexKabbalisticManuscr/page/n82)), also belonging to the school of R. Eleazar or R. [Yehudah Ha’Chassid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Samuel_of_Regensburg) (Scholem suggests the former) an almost identical fragment contains the word too, albeit in code. For further reading, see Scholem’s book ‘On the Kabbalah and Its Symbolism’ (specifically [174ff](https://the-eye.eu/public/concen.org/Occult%20Magick%20Symbols%20Sigils%2055%20ebooks/PDF/On%20the%20Kabbalah%20and%20Its%20Symbolism%20Gershom%20Scholem.pdf).) where he discusses this topic at length (beginning at p. 158).

Comment: +1 Although note that that he is not referring to the final ‘robot’ as a golem, but instead the unfinished, inanimate humanoid form.

Answer (score 3):

The earliest source I have found is in Zalman Zvi Aufhausen's יודישר טירייאק (published in 1615) on [page 7b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44801&st=&pgnum=19):

> אביר אונזרי **גולמיים** אין דיזן לאנדן מכין מיר ניט אויש ליימן זונדר
>   אויש מוטר לייב ווערין זיא גיבורן.‏
>
> In these lands, however, our Golems are not made from clay, but rather they are born from the bodies of their mothers.

(Translation by (and hat-tip to) R. Dr. Shnayer Z. Leiman in footnote 28 of [this article](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2010/05/golem-of-prague-in-recent-rabbinic.html) on the Seforim blog.)